# Can eth_subscribe newHead in Ethereum Provide baseFeePerGas Directly?

Tags: websocket, eip-1559

I'm working with Ethereum's `eth_subscribe` method, specifically subscribing to `newHeads` to get real-time information about new blocks. My goal is to retrieve the `baseFeePerGas` for each new block.

However, it seems that the `newHeads` subscription does not include the `baseFeePerGas` in its payload but only `gasLimit` and `gasUsed`. Currently, I am considering an additional request to the Ethereum node using `eth_getBlockByNumber` to fetch complete block details, including the `baseFeePerGas`, for each new block notified by `newHeads`.

My question is: Is there a way to directly obtain the `baseFeePerGas` from the `eth_subscribe newHead` method? Or is my current approach of using `eth_getBlockByNumber` the only way to access this information?